# how to represent a n-byte array in less than 2*n characters

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic, hex, number-formatting

given that a n-byte array can be represented as a 2*n character string using hex, is there a way to represent the n-byte array in less than 2*n characters?

for example, typically, an integer(int32) can be considered as a 4-byte array of data

Comment: What's an n-byte number?

Comment: @Dingo: with your comment *"Search the web for Base64"*, it's hard to tell at first sight if you're answering to *yamspog* or to *Jacob*, which is why you should use "@...:" before your comment ;)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The advantage of hex is that splitting an 8-bit byte into two equal halves is about the simplest thing you can do to map a byte to printable ASCII characters.  More efficient methods consider multiple bytes as a block:

---

Base-64 uses 64 ASCII characters to represent 6 bits at a time.  Every 3 bytes (i.e. 24 bits) are split into 4 6-bit base-64 digits, where the "digits" are:

```
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/
```

(and if the input is not a multiple of 3 bytes long, a 65th character, "`=`", is used for padding at the end).  Note that there are some variant forms of base-64 use different characters for the last two "digits".

---

Ascii85 is another representation, which is somewhat less well-known, but commonly used: it's often the way that binary data is encoded within PostScript and PDF files.  This considers every 4 bytes (big-endian) as an unsigned integer, which is represented as a 5-digit number in base 85, with each base-85 digit encoded as ASCII code 33+n (i.e. "`!`" for 0, up to "`u`" for 84) -  plus a special case where the single character "`z`" may be used (instead of "`!!!!!`") to represent 4 zero bytes.

(Why 85?  Because 84<sup>5</sup> < 2<sup>32</sup> < 85<sup>5</sup>.)

Comment: +1 for a great explanation, I've never heard of Base85 before.

Answer (score 4):

yes, using binary (in which case it takes n bytes, not surprisingly), or using any base higher than 16, a common one is base 64.

Answer (score 2):

It might depend on the exact numbers you want to represent.  For instance, the number 9223372036854775808, which requres 8 bytes to represent in binary, takes only 4 bytes in ascii, if you use the product of primes representation (which is "2^63").

Answer (score 1):

How about [base-64](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64)?

It all depends on what characters you're willing to use in your encoding (i.e. representation).

Answer (score 1):

Base64 fits 6 bits in each character, which means that 3 bytes will fit in 4 characters.

Answer (score 1):

Using 65536 of about 90000 defined Unicode characters you may represent binary string in N/2 characters.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Use more characters than just 0-9 and a-f. A single character (assuming 8-bit) can have 256 values, so you can represent an n-byte number in n characters.

If it needs to be printable, you can just choose some set of characters to represent various values. A good option is base-64 in that case.